# How to search for multiple strings in a log file using less command in unix?

Tags: linux, parsing, unix, less-unix

I want to search for multiple strings in a log file. Only those entries should be highligted where all the search strings are there in same line. Can i use less command for this or any other better option. My log file size is typically few GBs.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you want to search for `string1` or `string2`, use `/string1|string2`.
You said you wanted lines where you find both:

```
/string1.*string2
```

When you do not know the order in the line and want to see the complete line, you will need

```
/.*string1.*string2.*|.*string2.*string1.*
```

Or shorter

```
/.*(string1.*string2|string2.*string1).*
```

Combining more words without a fixed order will become a mess, and filtering first with `awk` is nice.

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me. I personally prefer less over awk because of "if file is open i can quickly change the search string, search forward/backward from the current location." Ability to search for multiple strings with less is a bonus.

Comment: You prefer it because this answer just tackles *two* search patterns. This get's super complicated when you increase the number of patterns or the patterns are more complex. *three* patterns are almost impossible to type.

Comment: @hek2mgl agree, in my case order of search strings is known and i have just 2 or 3 search strings max, so its preferred. Otherwise like you suggested awk with less is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

Use `awk` to filter the file and `less` to view the filtered result:

```
awk '/pattern1/ && /pattern2/ && /pattern3/' file.log | less
```

If the file is big you may want to use `stdbuf` to see results earlier in `less`:

```
stdbuf awk '/pattern1/ && /pattern2/ && /pattern3/' file.log | less
```